# Are $c_1y_1$ and $c_2y_2$ also solutions of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions of $$y''+6y'−5y=x, $$ then $c_1y_1+c_2y_2$ is also a solution of the equation.

I tried to solve it by linearity of differentiation and got that the statement is false but my teacher told me it's true. Can somebody explain or show me why?

Comment: You should ask your teacher to prove that it’s true.

Comment: You are right! If it was $=0$ instead of $=x$, then the statement would have been true. (This has to do with homogeneous/inhomogeneous differential equations).

Answer (score 0):

Well, substituting c1y1+c2y2 into the LHS we get c1(y1''+6y1'-5y1)+c2(y2''+6y2'-5y)=(c1+c2)x. So this is only true when c1+c2=1.
If this was a homogeneous equation (I.e. RHS is zero) then it would hold in general.

Comment: (please use mathjax)